# R - How to remove missing values and Nan in Dplyr Summarize function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find out quartile info on a dataset that has a calculated column 'calCTRLPV' (Landing Page Views/Impressions). For some rows, it will be NA as the numerator might be 0 or unavailable.
In trying to run summarize in dplyr, I'm getting below error. How can I correct the dataset for summarize to work correctly? Thanks.

*Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `calCTRLPV`.
x missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
i Input `calCTRLPV` is `quantile(calCTRLPV, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))`.*

```
trafficdata %>% 
group_by(Platform) %>%  
summarise(quantile = scales::percent(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)),
calCTRLPV = quantile(calCTRLPV, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))
```

Comment: Add `na.rm=TRUE`?

Comment: FYI, this is an issue with `quantile`, and while the error includes `summarise`, it is also a victim here. The problem is within and needs to be resolved within `quantile(.)` (and `mean` and `sd` and many other functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `na.rm` to `TRUE`:

```
trafficdata %>% 
  group_by(Platform) %>%  
  summarise(quantile = scales::percent(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)),
            calCTRLPV = quantile(calCTRLPV, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE))
```